# tibble shaping to spread a factor across multiple variables to factor out rows

Tags: r, normalization, reshape, forecasting, tidyverse

Note, this differs from the question "[How to reshape data from long to wide format?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5890584/how-to-reshape-data-from-long-to-wide-format)" in 2 ways:

1. There are a multiplicity of destination columns to be qualified by
   the single factor column.
2. The title of this question specified "tibble", implying `tidyverse`
   solutions are preferred.

Executing:

```
set.seed(14)
df <- data.frame(geo = LETTERS[1:2], time = c(2000,2000,2001,2001),
                     X = rnorm(4, 0, 1),
                     Y = rnorm(4, 0, 2))
head(df)
```

produces something like:

```
  geo time          X           Y
1   A 2000 -0.6618498 -0.07228116
2   B 2000  1.7189542  2.46389035
3   A 2001  2.1216670 -0.12976154
4   B 2001  1.4971537  2.13798746
```

What I want to do is reshape to `spread` `time` and end up with two rows with values for `geo`: `A` and `B`.

This would produce something like:

```
geo          X.2000           Y.2000          X.2001           Y.2001
  A      -0.6618498      -0.07228116       2.1216670      -0.12976154
  B       1.7189542       2.46389035       1.4971537       2.13798746
```

Comment: In base R, `reshape(df, direction = "wide", idvar = "geo", timevar = "time")`. With the `tidyverse`, you'll have to `gather`, `unite`, and then `spread`. `dcast` from "data.table" on a `data.table` can also do this without first `melt`ing the data.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to reshape data from long to wide format?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5890584/how-to-reshape-data-from-long-to-wide-format)

Comment: Not worth an answer, but for completeness, `data.table::dcast(as.data.table(df), geo ~ time, value.var = c("X", "Y"))`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The *tidy* approach is:

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  gather(key, value, -c(geo, time)) %>%
  unite(key, c(key, time), sep = ".") %>%
  spread(key, value)

#   geo     X.2000   X.2001      Y.2000     Y.2001
# 1   A -0.6618498 2.121667 -0.07228116 -0.1297615
# 2   B  1.7189542 1.497154  2.46389035  2.1379875
```

Comment: As I specified 'tibble' in the title of the question, `tidyverse` is preferred.

Comment: Unfortunately, this solution changes all the spread column classes to "character" if any of them don't match "numeric".

Answer (score 0):

We can use `reshape` function

```
reshape(df, direction = "wide", idvar = "geo", timevar = "time")
```

and it gives us the results that you wish

```
geo     X.2000      Y.2000   X.2001     Y.2001
1   A -0.6618498 -0.07228116 2.121667 -0.1297615
2   B  1.7189542  2.46389035 1.497154  2.1379875
```